# Hotkey doesn't work as expected

Tags: autohotkey

I don't understand why the script in my example doesn't work as expected.

Open any text editor, select some text, press Ctrl-C to copy it in clipboard. Then, launch the script.

*Expected behaviour:* If I press Ctrl-V, it should be shown message box `ok`. If I press Ctrl-Shift-V, it should be shown the same message box. (There should be no difference).

*Actual behaviour:* If I press Ctrl-Shift-V, there shown `error` message box. Why?

```
^v::MsgBox, ok
return

^+v::MsgBox, error
return

^+v::^v
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot redefine hotkeys; you cannot define them more than once.  When it comes to defining HotKeys and HotStrings, autohotkey is more a declarative language than a procedural one.

If you want to change the behavior of a key combination, put logic in the script. For example:

```
; Press F2 to change the behavior of ^+v
f2::
  condition := !condition
  return

^+v::
  if (condition)
    MsgBox, ok
  else
    MsgBox, error
  return
```